# When to repeat Shmoneh Esrei when there is chazarat hashatz?

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, mistakes, chazarat-hashatz

Sometimes a person needs to repeat Shmoneh Esrei. Some example cases: *tashlumin*, if one forgot *ya'aleh v'yavoh*, or said the wrong *birkat hashanim*.

This person is davening Shacharit, and immediately after he finishes his Shmoneh Esrei, he realizes that he needs to repeat it. Should he start right away, or say (at least the beginning) in sync with the chazzan? Does it make a difference why he's repeating it (mistake in this one, or *tashlumin*)?
If he says it with the chazzan, can/should he say kedusha also?

Comment: related (in that the purpose of Chaz"hash might be more) http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16958/why-do-we-still-do-chazarat-hashatz

Comment: He can just listen to the Chazzan and say Amen if he wants... IAE I think we have a question around here of if there is still a need to try and pray with a Minyan in this sort of case.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the accepted rule is that if he can finish repeating the shemoneh esrei before the chazzan reaches kedusha (so that he can answer along with the congregation), he should repeat it immediately. Otherwise, he should wait till the chazzan begins his repetition and say the entire shemoneh esrei along with him word by word including kedusha. (I believe the Aruch HaShulchan tries to argue that he should even say the birchat kohanim replacement prayer that the chazzan inserts in *chu"l*.) There's no real reason to distinguish between why he's repeating it since the idea is that he needs to say shemoneh esrei since his original didn't count. This is the same rule as if he came to shul late.