# Standing during chazaras hashat"z

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, standing-sitting, chazarat-hashatz

During the chazan's repetition of the amidah, do the people in the minyan need to stand? (for parts other than kedusha and modim de'rabanan).

Comment: [Yoma 87b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=87b&format=pdf)

Answer (score 4):

The *Shulchan Aruch* doesn't say so, but see Rabbi Eliezer Melamed who [says](http://ph.yhb.org.il/02-19-03/) that it is preferable to stand, because the rest are considered "partners" with the *chazzan* in prayer. However, it is not obligatory.

He relies on the [Mishnah Berura (124, 20)](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%93) who says that the *tzibbur*, by listening and *lechaven*, are semi-praying as well. And he also says this is an old *minhag* ("מנהג קדמונים"), and he adds that one may not sit near the *chazzan* (within four *amot*).

Rabbi Melamed also mentions the [Kaf Ha'Chayim (124, 24)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41181&st=&pgnum=145), who mentions some more sources that mostly side with standing.

Answer (score 4):

See [this review of the Sidur of Rav J. B. Soloveitchik](http://www.jewishmag.com/165mag/book_soloveitchik_sidur/book_soloveitchik_sidur.htm) .

> It was his practice to stand with his feet together through the entire
>   repetition of the Amida.

In the [Rosh Hashono Machzor “Mesoras Harav”](http://www.levinejudaica.com/catalog/machzor-mesoras-haravrosh-hashanahh-the-rav-jb-soloveitchik-p-5560.html) , the section on his hanhagos explains that the Rambam in Hilchos Tefiloh 8 (4) refers to the  repetition as “the prayer of the congregation” which means that it is essentially a second Amida. Rav Soloveitchik held that a person's posture should reflect that and that is why he stood with his feet together through the entire repetition of the Amida.

I see this is also discussed in the answer to [Why do we still do chazarat hashatz?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16958/why-do-we-still-do-chazarat-hashatz/16980#16980) .

Comment: "It was his practice" <> "it is halacha." The sheliach tzibbur is most assuredly required to do so, since that is part of the performance of his shelichus. In a similar vein, certain rabbanim had the practice of standing stock still when davening, yet never paskened that as a requirement. We see regularly statements in the Talmud of "machmirim al atzmam," and that would seem to apply here.