# Making Everyday Like Yom Kippur

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, yom-kippur, chazarat-hashatz

I have toyed with the idea of importing an aspect of Yom Kippur into my everyday life and am constantly looking for (homiletically) a connection which would draw the essence of Yom Kippur into every day life. I think I have found one and am looking for sources which might have made this connection before (and more eloquently than) I have.

One thing which makes Yom Kippur unique is that during it, there are five shmoneh esrei-prayer services (maariv, shacharit, musaf, mincha and ne'ilah) as distinct from weekdays (3 Amidah services) and holidays (4).

However, when one sees the Chazarat Hashatz repetition as a [distinct](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16964/1362) prayer experience, then daily, one experiences 5 prayer services (3 b'Lachash and 2 Chazarat Hashatz, at least as subject of fanciful homily).

Are there any sources which draw together the 5 shmoneh esrei services on Y"K and during every day?

Comment: As an aside, this is the exact reason Muslims pray five times a day- Mohammed asked how many times Jews prayed on their holiest day of the year and decided to do likewise

Comment: IMHO, maybe a good way to incorporate Yom Kippur into everyday life is to do the repentance/teshuvah part of it on a daily basis all year long, instead of waiting for the Days of Awe or Yom Kippur, set yourself straight with whatever you might have done EVERY DAY, hopefully starting fresh every morning of the year with a "clean slate", instead of letting them all pile up.